# Website Messed Up Only If Accessed In Past

Tags: html, css, caching, cookies, cross-browser

So my website: [ropinranch.com](http://ropinranch.com/)

looks FINE on any browser (so far) if you haven't accessed the page in the past. But for any of my previous users, it looks messed up when they load it.

We've all cleared all of our cookies, and emptied our cache. I even edited a new image on the page to see if that would change and it DID.

I cannot think any other way the page would be keeping memory of it. 
One of my testers said that if they had the page bookmarked in the past of it working fine, that when clicking on the bookmark it loads fine still -- but typing in a URL fails.

Any other ideas on what I'm missing here?

**Update: I realized what happened -- but I'm unsure how to fix. 
https://ropinranch.com WORKS 
but 
www.ropinranch.com does not. I know theres a setting in my c-pannel to change this but I don't know what it's called**

Comment: If you are just testing, could you try passing a timestamp or random number in the URL ( manually , just for testing ) and check. Eg : `http://ropinranch.com?f=141414542343` (each time with a diff number )

Comment: @Varun how does that work..... lol you've just mind blown me

Comment: I also discovered it only a few days back! :P . If you are constantly getting a cached copy of a page for whatever reasons. Try passing a random number/string with it, the browser then fetches a new copy each time. It certainly worked for me in case of images, works for pages too!
@London O'Connell

Comment: @Varun That is insane... I'm glad that worked though because now I at least know the code works. Is there anyway to have it work for any of my users though or will it always be stuck in a cached page?

Comment: Have you enabled server side caching?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to, any way you could explain that? @Varun

Comment: I am not a server guy :P but there are page/resources caching options in the server that if disabled should prevent other users from getting the old copy rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me temporarily:

By Varun: If you are just testing, could you try passing a timestamp or random number in the URL ( manually , just for testing ) and check. Eg : http://ropinranch.com?f=141414542343 (each time with a diff number )

But What I did was I had to go through the server and reroute all traffic to my SSL site rather than things of www. or http://

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+F5 to reload the page without caching.

Comment: That didn't work :/ I'm looking into server side caching to see if I can fix it with everyone